# What is causing these directories to be hidden?

Tags: c#, linux, docker, asp.net-core

I've got the following program:

```
public class Program
{
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dir = args[0];
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
            Console.WriteLine(file);
    }
}
```

I've stuck this in a docker container and execute it on a debian machine like so;

```
docker run test /lib
```

And the results:

```
/lib/firmware
/lib/hdparm
/lib/init
/lib/lsb
/lib/modprobe.d
/lib/systemd
/lib/terminfo
/lib/udev
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

However this is not all the directories in `/lib`.  I thought there was a permissions issue blocking some of the entries to not be displayed, but running `ls -pl | grep '/'` results in the following:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    21 Feb  2  2014 cpp -> /etc/alternatives/cpp
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Sep 12 13:35 discover/
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root  4096 Sep 12 14:49 firmware/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Sep 12 13:35 hdparm/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Sep 12 13:34 ifupdown/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Sep 12 14:47 init/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Sep 12 13:33 lsb/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Sep 12 13:33 modprobe.d/
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  4096 Sep 12 13:49 modules/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Sep 12 13:34 modules-load.d/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Sep 12 13:46 startpar/
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root  4096 Sep 12 13:47 systemd/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Sep 12 13:47 sysvinit/
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 Feb  1  2014 terminfo/
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Sep 12 13:50 udev/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 12288 Sep 18 22:07 x86_64-linux-gnu/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 20480 Sep 12 13:49 xtables/
```

How can I get the original program to list all the directories like `ls` does?  Is there another command I use to determine what the difference is between the directories that are displayed and those that aren't?

**DockerFile**

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-beta7

ADD . /app

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["./ConsoleTest"]
```

Comment: it would help to see your Dockerfile, or have some more info, like a reproducer